# How to pass state from redux to class based component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

As I am new to all this things, I have some troubles passing ( reading ) state from redux to react class based components.

On class based component I added connect, and mapStateToProps but I am not sure how to access it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

    class MyComp extends Component {
        render() { 
            return (
               <div>
                   // data from props
                </div>
           )
        }
     }


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    getVal: state.testReducer.testState
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComp);
```

What I am looking for is to get value from that state. 
Some detailed example, tutorial or similar would we great so I can understand it better.

Sorry, this is probably noob question...

I was looking for read, set and pass data in and out of redux and between components but I just felt overwhelmed, hope for some clarification.

Comment: when you use HOC connect it passes this value to your props. You can access it via ```this.props.getVal```

Comment: this.props.getVal ?

Comment: Yes. I would recommend you reading the react docs first.

Comment: Please check the ["Redux `conect`"](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have simply to access by using `this.props.getVal`.
All properties mapped properly with `mapStateToProps` are injected to component props.